# Why main activity frame width is larger than height even if it's in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why when i'm testing my aplication, the IOS Simulator starts in portrait mode, so in
viewDidLoad function self.view.frame.size.width equals to 1024 but
inside function called by button being clicked it's 768? I haven't change device orientation. I also pasted below descriptions of self.view from first and second function.

before

```
Printing description of self->_view:
<UIView: 0x8b20720; frame = (0 0; 1024 748); 
autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b291c0>>
```

after

```
<UIView: 0x8b1da70; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; 
autoresize =  RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b20810>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`UIView` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame):

> **frame**
>
> Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Use the `bounds` property instead.

Comment: Even the `bounds` will probably at `{0, 0, 1024, 768}` in `viewDidLoad` and stay that way until `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `viewDidLoad` set the `.transform` property of `self.view` like so:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

And see if that helps. It will return the UIView (here `self.view`) to its original intended orientation.

It should also be noted that the iOS Simulator is **hopeless** for orientation bugs. It is always best to test these things on a device, as the Simulator doesn't have an Accelerometer or Gyroscope.